# Thousand Separator not coming in my facebook payments Description

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-payments

If my product is to sell "100000 coins for 1$" how can i display 100000 coins with comma separator like 100,000 Coins on facebook payments native popup

Comment: I don’t think you can, the Payment dialog does not offer any such formatting options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we are creating html data using meta tags for product creation to facebook, we are sending a property called og:title. Whatever we send in this title tag will appear as description. So, we have to format number into currency format and send that in title to make it appear the way we want.